Spark EMR long running transformation job GC is taking more time
I have transformation job running in spark emr (7.1). This job is compute intensive as it calculates approx_percentile and other aggregated function. The GC is taking more time. I would like to know if any way to resolve this.
Cluster Details

1 Primary5 Core151 Task -r5.16xlarge 64 vCore, 512 GiB memory, EBS only storage

Spark submit command used
[![spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster  --conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1 \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false \
--conf spark.network.timeout=5400s  --conf spark.files.fetchTimeout=600s \
--conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer \
--conf spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes=536870912 \
--conf spark.shuffle.compress=true --conf spark.shuffle.spill.compress=true \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.coalescePartitions.enabled=false \
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3.multipart.th.fraction.parts.completed=0.99 \
--conf spark.sql.objectHashAggregate.sortBased.fallbackThreshold=4000000 \
--conf spark.reducer.maxReqsInFlight=1 \
--conf spark.network.timeout=1200s \
--conf spark.executor.cores=5 \
--conf spark.executor.instances=1600 \
--conf spark.executor.memory=35g --conf spark.driver.memory=60g --conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=4g --conf spark.driver.memoryOverhead=4g \
--conf spark.sql.adaptive.enabled=true \
--conf spark.default.parallelism=16000  \
--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=16000 \
--conf spark.eventLog.rolling.maxFileSize=128m --conf spark.eventLog.rolling.enabled=true --conf spark.history.fs.eventLog.rolling.maxFilesToRetain=1 \
--conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-XX:+UseG1GC" --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-XX:+UseG1GC " \
--class com.eda.rrr.xxx.transform.kakakPerformance s3://searpan/emr_jar/Seambly-1.0.jar --re_id 1 --period weekly --dt_date 2024-06-08 --pan_date 20240608][1]][1] 



